# What is constructor.prototype refering to?

Tags: typescript

Reading the documentation for Decorators in typescript (I stumpled upon this snippet:

```
function sealed(constructor: Function) {
    Object.seal(constructor);
    Object.seal(constructor.prototype);
}
```

> When @sealed is executed, it will seal both the constructor and its prototype.

What does `constructor.prototype` point to? This prototypical inheritance can be a tad confusing at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that out by looking at a simple example and the resulting javascript:

```
class A {
    fn1() { }
}

class B extends A {
    fn2() { }
}
```

The compiled js:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.prototype.fn1 = function () { };
    return A;
}());
var B = (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    B.prototype.fn2 = function () { };
    return B;
}(A));
```

The `constructor` which the decorator function receives is `A` or `B` which are the constructor functions, if you type `A` in the developers console you'll see:

```
function A() {
    }
```

And something similar for `B`:

```
function B() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
```

The `constructor.prototype` part refers to the prototype of the class, so `A.prototype` will show:

```
Object {fn1: function, constructor: function}
```

And `B.prototype` will show:

```
A {constructor: function, fn2: function}
```